# Selenium sends unwanted tab ([\t]) to input field that has validation

Tags: selenium, junit, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver

I need to fill multiple values in a div, it worked before, but somehow when migrated to a new environment it suddenly started recognising these [\t] symbols in the code and my page throws an error.
There **was** a tab key after every translation I sent, but I removed it.

The code:

```
public void setTranslationsFor(final String elementId, final String  translation) throws InterruptedException {
    try {
        for (final WebElement input : translationElementsOf(elementId)) {

            input.clear();
            input.sendKeys(textOrVariableValue(translation));
            if (isExplorer()) {
                ((JavascriptExecutor) driver()).executeScript("$(arguments[0]).change(); return true;", input);
            }
            sleep();
        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {

        makeScreenshot();
        testBlocked();
        throw e;
    }
}

protected final List<WebElement> translationElementsOf(final String name) {
    return elementsOf(name + "_translations", ".//input[starts-with(@id, '" + name + "_') and @id != '" + name + "_x-keyword']");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED.

It was a problem with one of my voids inside the Webdriver that sent the keys instead of the value of the keys.